# Background outside CSS Bottom Border

Tags: html, css, border

first question here so please be kind! I am designing a website and I've been asked to frame pictures in sine-like borders. So far I've gotten around to it by creating a container div with 3 divs: the first for the downward bend, the second is just straight (I'm considering the idea of removing it later on) and the third one does the upward bend.
[Here's a screenshot of the current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTDof.jpg)
So this is the the current code:

```css
.border {
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.bord1 {
  margin-top: 4vh;
  height: 4vh;
  flex: 1;
  border-top: solid 5px;
  border-color: #e4ae03 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.bord2 {
  margin-top: 4vh;
  flex: 1;
  display: inline;
  height: 4vh;
  border-top: 5px solid #e4ae03;
}

.bord3 {
  margin-top: -4vh;
  flex: 1;
  height: 4vh;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #e4ae03 transparent;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="bord1 top top-bord"></div>
  <div class="bord2 top top-bord"></div>
  <div class="bord3 bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I'm really trying to figure out how to get the last segment white, as it's created by rounding the bottom right corner, so the white background would have to be "outside" the div.

I know this might be a stupid question, but here it is! Thanks!

*Edit: Sorry everyone, here is an image of what I'm trying to do[image: ![]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFQQv.jpg)

Comment: @ankuragarwal : here comes your comment : `Could you please elaborate the last line of your question as to what is that you are expecting. I could not understand what you are referring to as last segment. may be add a jpeg of what is actually expected.`

Comment: I'm quite anxious for the answer to this one in pure CSS too. I would simply recommend doing this by png, but I can't figure how to do the upper-right and lower-left border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would need minor adjustments to the spacing, but something along these lines? (I used black/white backgrounds to show the sections, but these could be swapped or even made transparent.

```css
body{background-color:black;}

.border{
   overflow: hidden;
   align-items: center;
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   background-color:white;
}
.bord1{
   margin-top: 4vh;
   height: 4vh;
   flex:1;
   border-top: solid 5px;
   border-color:#e4ae03 rgba(0,0,0,0) transparent transparent;
   border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
   z-index: 999;
   background-color:black;
}
.bord2 {
   margin-top: 4vh;
   flex: 1;
   display: inline;
   height: 4vh;
   border-top: 5px solid #e4ae03;
   background-color:black;
}
.bord3{
   border-bottom: 5px solid;
   border-color: transparent transparent #e4ae03 transparent;
   border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
   background-color:white;
   height:4vh;
}
.bord3-layer{
   flex: 1;
   height: 9vh;
   display: block;
   background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <head>
      <style>
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="border">
  <div class="bord1 top top-bord"></div>
  <div class="bord2 top top-bord"></div>
  <div class="bord3-layer">
    <div class="bord3 bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: If you're having trouble with the heights/sizing: applying `div{box-sizing:border-box;}` might help

Comment: This would be a really nice solution, unfortunately though the background of the page has to be a gradient, so turning the parts I don't need black couldn't work! Thanks though!

Comment: Ok, in the end through this method I've been able to complete the layout I was looking for! I'll be posting my solution here, in case anyone is interested! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in the end I was able to fix the layout using a system of inner divs, here is how I handled it:

```css
.container {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: -5vh;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px;
  padding-top: 5vh;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  color: #b3b5b3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1b2716, #000000 80%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #1b2716, #000000 80%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1b2716, #000000 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(left, #1b2716, #000000 80%);
  min-height: 75vh;
}
.top {
  box-shadow: inset 0 6px 0 0px #243c51;
}

.bottom {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0px #243c51;
}
.border{
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.bord1{
  margin-top: 4vh;
  height: 4vh;
  flex:1;
  border-top: solid 5px;
  border-color:#e4ae03 rgba(0,0,0,0) transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.bord1-bot{
  background: white;
}

.bord2 {
  margin-top: 4vh;
  flex: 1;
  display: inline;
  height: 4vh;
  border-top: 5px solid #e4ae03;
}

.bord2-bot {
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 4vh;
  flex: 1;
  display: inline;
  height: 4vh;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #e4ae03;
}

.bord3{
  flex: 1;
  height: 4vh;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #e4ae03 transparent;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
}

.bord3-top {
  margin-top: 0vh;
  background: black;
}
.bord3-bot {
  margin-top: 0vh;
  background: white;
}
.bord3-bottom {
  background: white;
}
.bord3-layer-top{
  flex:1;
  height: 8.5vh;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

.bord3-layer-bot{
  flex:1;
  height: 8.5vh;
  display: block;
}
.bord1-layer-top{
  flex:1;
  height: 8.5vh;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

.bot-bord {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1b2716, #000000 240%);
}

.text-con {
  padding: 2vw;
  z-index: 2;
}
.image-within {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.top-bord {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="border">
  <div class="bord1 top top-bord"></div>
  <div class="bord2 top top-bord"></div>
  <div class="bord3-layer-top">
  <div class="bord3 bottom bord3-top"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="image-within">
</div>
<div class="border">
  <div class="bord1-layer-top"><div class="bord1 top bot-bord"></div></div>
  <div class="bord2-bot bottom"></div>
  <div class="bord3-layer-bot">
  <div class="bord3 bottom bord3-bot"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is really messy at the moment, so I'll have to clean it up a bit and work on keeping all the items constantly aligned, but it's looking pretty good right now! Thanks LegendaryJLD!